# Using the Egyptian Hieroglyphic control characters

Tags: html, unicode, formatting

The Unicode standard now contains control characters for the formatting of Egyptian hieroglyphics. (Nine characters: 13430-8). In principle (my understanding) is that they are intended to work as so:

in which code 13430 (EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH VERTICAL JOINER) indicates that one sign should be put above the other, like this:

[image: correctly formatted glyphs]

Unfortunately, there seems to be no support for these characters at this point.

Particularly I am wanting to implement something for the web, i.e., I would like to display correctly formatted hieroglyphs without having to generate an image on the backend. Ideally, something like `<span class="hieroglyphic-unicode"></span>` would display correctly.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't directly embed an image as I have too little reputation, but I generated a larger scale image

Comment: When I try to save the post with the image embedded it gives the error: "You need at least 10 reputation to post images." The link worked for me, but I've tried it another way - hopefully it works now.

Answer (score 2):

Peter Constable's comments are correct, rendering Egyptian Hieroglyphs in fonts is very complex and takes time. There is a working group which combines the talents of Egyptologists and Unicode experts to ensure that the desired rendering capabilities are developed. We expect fonts to start becoming available during 2023 after platforms have had time to update to Unicode 15. As Peter pointed out, [github.com/microsoft/font-tools](https://github.com/microsoft/font-tools) is a good place to watch for progress.

Answer (score 1):

The approach taken in your HTML looks correct, but I can't find any support for those Egyptian hieroglyphics control characters, even though they were added in Unicode 12.0 back in March, 2019.

One reason for that may have been the ongoing requests to add further control characters to provide richer support for combining hieroglyphics, so there was a reluctance to commit to doing anything while those proposed enhancements were still being discussed. However, [those changes have now been approved](https://www.unicode.org/L2/L2022/22023-script-adhoc-rept.pdf) (see Item 4 "Egyptian Hieroglyphs", pages 6 through 10).

Hopefully those changes will be included in Unicode 15 which is due to be released this September, but I couldn't find any documentation confirming that. If not, you may face a long wait! In the meantime I think you are stuck with using images, although that approach may not be practicable, depending on your requirements.

See this thread, [Support Egyptian Hieroglyph Format Controls #1469](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-fonts/issues/1469), which confirms that there is no current support for the existing (Unicode 12) control characters with Google's **Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs** font. A comment near the end of the thread discussing support for Egyptian hieroglyph Format controls once Unicode 15 is released states "*we will consider it along with all of the other Unicode changes, bug fixes, etc...*".

Comment: Another proposal at [An Extension to the three control characters for
Egyptian Hieroglyphs and some additional remarks](https://www.unicode.org/L2/L2016/16214-egyptian-ctrl-chars.pdf).

Comment: That document suggests a reason why things seem to move so slowly: _"The expert user base, understandably, has little experience with using complex scripts in Unicode and it is important experience is gained using a basic system before considering the best way to make specialist additions."_ Egyptologists know very little about Unicode, and Unicode experts know very little about Egyptian hieroglyphics!

Comment: It always takes some time for characters to be supported in products after they are added to Unicode, and especially when there is complex rendering or font implementation involved. This might be of interest: https://github.com/microsoft/font-tools

Comment: @PeterConstable Yes, your link is of interest - thanks. Please consider posting your own answer which will surely be more authoritative than mine, and may also be helpful to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for the web, there has been support (i.e. a JavaScript implementation) for the first 9 control characters (Unicode 12) since the beginning (2018):

https://mjn.host.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/egyptian/res/js/

This uses HTML canvas, which is admittedly not ideal. There is now a better solution, using SVG, which also covers the new 29 control characters from Unicode 15:

https://nederhof.github.io/hierojax/

It is the implementation in OpenType that is really difficult (it is being worked on).