# Unicode Egyptian cartouche

Tags: unicode

Similar to [Using the Egyptian Hieroglyphic control characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72575948/using-the-egyptian-hieroglyphic-control-characters)

I am interested in understand and using the [egyptian unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_Hieroglyphs_(Unicode_block)) [cartouche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartouche) characters u+13286  &    u+13287 
to enclose other symbols (e.g for names).

The classic example is for Pharaohs. E.g.
[image]

(from https://egyptian-history.com/blogs/egyptian-symbols/egyptian-cartridge)
There are some other examples here https://www.mobilefish.com/services/hieroglyphs/hieroglyphs.php

However I am unclear on several points.

1. Is it rational to expect these to be rendered as a border around any (non-control) characters they enclose? or can that only be expected for egpytian hieroglyphs?
2. Does unicode mandate/suggest that they should be rendered as a full border at all?

3. Is there any software that actually renders these correctly (or plans to) in the above sense?
   So far I have found that the symbols themselves are widely recognised and rendered as individual symbol but I have not come across anything that renders the border. Leading me to think that either the symbols were never intended to be rendered this way or they are still too new and niche.

My reading of https://www.unicode.org/L2/L2021/21248-egyptian-controls.pdf for example says yes to both 1 & 2 for u+1343c & u+1343d. However, I have not found anything that can render those even as an isolated symbol.

4. Are there any similar portions of unicode that can render a border around the symbols they contain?
   Do any of them have widespread rendering support?
5. Also I think cartouches can be horizontal, vertical or possibly divided into quarters. Are there additional control symbols to support this?

For context I would ideally like to be able to display correctly one or more of:

- a browser
- a unicode aware editor
- via a unicode aware rendering library

Comment: You are probably already aware of Bug Report [Support Egyptian Hieroglyph Format Controls](https://github.com/notofonts/egyptian-hieroglyphs/issues/1) for Google's _Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs_ font. It looks like they intend to do something about this eventually, but there has been no recent activity (i.e. Since the release of Unicode 15.0).

Comment: I did not. That is useful.

Comment: Also see [this helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72575948/using-the-egyptian-hieroglyphic-control-characters/72579104#comment128237278_72579104) from @PeterConstable for a link to [any developments from Microsoft](https://github.com/microsoft/font-tools). But I fear you will be waiting for months, if not years, for progress; implementing support for this is non-trivial, and I suspect your suggestion that this functionality is _"too new and niche"_ is correct.

Answer (score 1):

L2/21-248 is a proposal, not an actual statement of the current state of Unicode. The relevant enclosure controls were added in [Unicode 15](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode15.0.0/ch11.pdf) (see page 450). This explains the rules for their use.

Actually rendering them requires a font that supports them. Unicode **encodes** text and defines various rules around manipulating it, but it does not render anything. That's the job of fonts. I don't know of any font that currently supports [U+1343C](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1343c/fontsupport.htm).

Given that Unicode 15 was not released until Sep 2022, this is a fairly complex thing to render correctly, and there is limited demand for it outside of specialized communities, I would not expect support outside of academic tools for some time. For earlier discussion of similar issues and further links, see [Using the Egyptian Hieroglyphic control characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72575948/using-the-egyptian-hieroglyphic-control-characters).

Comment: I'm not sure fonts render anything either. Traditionally a font is a particular static rendering of characters. It seems odd to be putting the work of combining glyphs onto the font rather than a renderer that uses a font. Putting it another way a font could be a set of bitmaps and shouldn't be executable. Its easy to see the lines blurring though. One day we may have a turing complete font. Apparently this is already possible - https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19358255 & https://gwern.net/turing-complete

Comment: If by "traditionally" you mean "before the mid 1980s or so," maybe. But certainly not for the last few decades. Fonts are full of logic. I often joke that the Zapfino font has almost achieved sentience.